# MySQL: Select between September and September

Tags: php, mysql, select

I am showing the sales in my Database using this select

```
SELECT YEAR( ordered_date ) AS Jahr, SUM( preis ) AS Preis, count(*) as Anzahl FROM wccrm_orders where typ = 'Brautkleid' GROUP BY YEAR(ordered_date) ORDER BY ordered_date ASC
```

This is working fine, currently the output is year (1-12), the number and the price. Now I need to achieve the following:

The Price, Count(*) and Year should not be shown from Jan to Dec, but from Sep to Sep. Is this possible? How can I achieve this?

Kind Regards,

Stefan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Subtract 9 months or add 3 months (I'm not sure what you want to call "Jahr"):

```
SELECT YEAR( ordered_date + interval 3 month) AS Jahr,
       SUM( preis ) AS Preis, count(*) as Anzahl
FROM wccrm_orders 
WHERE typ = 'Brautkleid'
GROUP BY Jahr
ORDER BY Jahr ASC;
```

Comment: Jahr is year in German.  And you should add the precise number of days (from jan 1) until september 1st.

Comment: @tonygil . . . There is no need to add exact days.  Adding 3 months does what the OP wants.  The OP is not clear about whether 2016-12-01 should be "2016" or "2017".

Comment: @Gordon : elegant

Comment: @Gordon: Very Cool - exactly what I wanted! Perfect! Thank you very much!